# Azure Devops Service Hooks (Webhook) fails with The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-service-hooks, azure-webhooks

I've configured a service hook -> webhook that invokes a remote HTTPS URL with a valid certificate.

When testing the webhook I get this error:

```
There was an error sending the request, so there was no response.  
Error(s):
    An error occurred while sending the request.
    The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
    You may not call this function on a different context than the original request
```

Invoking the same URL with curl everything is fine.

EDIT: Reading answers with a similar error I thought the problem could be related to the TLS version used by Azure Devops.

My remote service was enabled for TLS 1.3 and 1.2 and failed with <= 1.1.

I configured it to allow TLS 1.0 and 1.1 as well and I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had checked "Accept untrusted SSL certificates". Unchecking it fixed the problem.